# Find node with maximal (minimal) values of property in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have the following db:

```
CREATE (p1:Product {cost:10, name:'Hrundel'})
CREATE (p2:Product {cost:20, name:'Majora'})
CREATE (p3:Product {cost:30, name:'Elona'})

CREATE (s:Shop {name:'CarsMorpher'})

CREATE s-[:HAS]->(p1)
CREATE s-[:HAS]->(p2)
CREATE s-[:HAS]->(p3)
```

How can I find the name of the product that has lowest (highest) price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `max` and `min` to calculate highest and lowest, and do something like this:

```
MATCH (p:Product) 
WITH max(p.cost) as highestCost 
MATCH (p2:Product) 
where p2.cost=highestCost 
return p2;
```

Using `WITH` you can chain the results from the earlier query together with a second query.

A different way of doing it:

```
MATCH (p:Product) RETURN p 
ORDER BY p.cost DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

So this just lists them in descending order by price, and only gives you one (the maximum)